# Python program to read multiple files at a time

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a 1000 files in a folder named md_1.mdp, md_2.mdp, ..., md_1000.mdp and the 186th line of every file reads:

```
    gen_seed                 = 35086
```

This value is different in every file and it is what I want to extract and print as the output.
I have written the following code but it is not displaying any output.

```
    import numpy as np
    idx = np.arange(1,1000)
    for i in idx:
       f = open('/home/abc/xyz/mdp_200/md_'+str(i)+'.mdp','r')
       l = f.readlines()
       l = l[185].split(" ")
       flag = 0
       for k in l:
           if flag==1:
               if k!='':
                   print(k)
                   flag=0
           if k=="t=":
               flag=1
       f.close()
```

What should I add to this program so that it prints the required value for each file one by one in the order of md_1.mdp, md_2.mdp and so on?

Comment: Have you tested if the files open? If the lines are read? If there is an *exact* text `t=` anywhere in that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
    with open('/home/abc/xyz/mdp_200/md_'+ str(i)+ '.mdp') as fp:
        l = fp.readlines()
        print(l[185].split('=')[-1].strip())
```

or you can use [linecache.getline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline):

```
import linecache

for i in range(1, 1001):
    file = f'/home/abc/xyz/mdp_200/md_{i}.mdp'    
    line = linecache.getline(file, 185)
    print(line.split('=')[-1].strip())
```

after you get your line the split is done by `=` character